# convolution: how can I show that $(y*f)'(t) = (y'*f)(t) + y(0)f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

I have the following math problem from my intro to dif. eq. class: (so don't just give an answer)

> If the convolution $$ (y*f)(t) = \int_0^t y(t-v)f(v)\,dv$$
>   then show that $$ (y*f)'(t) = (y'*f)(t)+y(0)f(t) $$

---

So here's what I did:
\begin{align*}
  (y*f)'(t) &= \frac{d}{dt} \def\i#1{\int_0^t #1 \, dv}
 \i{y(t-v)f(v)}\\
            &= \i{\frac{d}{dt}\bigl(y(t-v)f(v)\bigr)} 
\tag 1\\
            &= \i{y'(t-v)f(v) + y(t-v)f'(v)}
\tag 2\\
&= \i{y'(t-v)f(v)} + \i{y(t-v)f'(v)}\\
&= y(t-t)f(t)-y(t-0)f(0) - \i{y(t-v)f'(v)} + \i{t(t-v)f'(v)} 
\tag 3\\
&= y(0)f(t)-y(t)f(0) \tag 4 
\end{align*}
where in

1. Leibniz's Rule
2. product rule
3. integration by parts
4. integrals cancel.

So this is clearly wrong according to the question so where do I go wrong?

EDIT:

Also how can I better understand the meaning of $$ (y'*f)(t) $$ in comparison to $$ (y*f)(t) $$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! If you plan to ask more questions here, you should [learn MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which will make your equations much easier to read.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, thanks, I will learn it, just don't have time at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, according to the chain rule, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t y(t-v)f(v)\,dv = 
y(t-t)f(t) + \int_0^t y'(t-v)f(v) \, dv = y(0)f(t) + (y' * f)(t) $$

---

Addendum: You did two mistakes: (1) You used Leibniz's rule wrong. You did not take into account that one integration limit depends on $t$, note that Leibniz's rule states that 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} F(t,v)\, dv = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(t,v)\, dt + f(t,b(t))b'(t) - f(t,a(t))a'(t) $$
which gives the above (what I wrote above).

(2) You did apply the product rule wrong, note that you are taking derivatives with respect to $t$, not $v$ and $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigl(f(t-v)g(v)\bigr) = f'(t-v)g(v) $$
as $g(v)$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Clearly this is what I am supposed to get, however the question in the book specifies that I should use Leibniz's Rule and I also need to show all my work. So this is more of a question on where did I make a mistake.

Comment: I did not leave off any steps and added something regarding your mistakes.